# how can I remove default menuItem in iOS16, including "Open Link" "Add to Reading list"

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, ios16, xcode14

In a custom `UITextView`, I override this function:

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

But it still shows two menuItems, "Open Link" and "Add to Reading list". I just want to show one "copy" item.

[image: Image showing an iOS popover]

Answer (score 0):

implement the method of UITextViewDelegate below this answer,retun an empty UIMenu that will disable all edit menu, you can try to only add the copy menu.

```
- (UIMenu *)textView:(UITextView *)textView editMenuForTextInRange:(NSRange)range suggestedActions:(NSArray<UIMenuElement *> *)suggestedActions  API_AVAILABLE(ios(16.0)) {
    return [UIMenu menuWithChildren:@[]];
}
```